# Await/Async not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise, async-await

I want to process batches of data in series, like shown in the code below. In this context a single batch is simply an array containing values. So the function sendInBatches() expects an array of arrays as input.

```
async sendInBatches(batches) {
    for (const batch of batches) {
       const promises = batch.map(x => asyncMethod(x));
       await Promise.all(promises);
    }
}
```

Below is the code for asyncMethod(). Note that the asyncMethod() doesnt actually do anything with the provided argument yet. It simply returns a Promise that resolves after 1 second.

```
asyncMethod(batch){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                console.log('x');
                resolve();
            }
            , 1000,
        );
    });

}
```

I try running the code like this:

```
sendInBatches([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).then(console.log('done'));
```

This provides the output:

```
done
x
x
x
```

While I want it to return:

```
x
x
x
done
```

I cant figure out whats going wrong here, do you guys have an idea?

Comment: You are passing `console.log("done")` into the `.then` directly, not as part of a function. So it will evaluate it immediately. Instead, try `.then(() => console.log("done"))` and you should get the result you want.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the quick response. Cant believe I overlooked something so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

> You are passing `console.log("done")` into the `.then` directly, not as
>   part of a function. So it will evaluate it immediately. Instead, try
>   `.then(() => console.log("done"))` and you should get the result you
>   want.

see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630238/await-async-not-working-in-for-loop#comment84257497_48630238) of CRice